# Prove continuity from above and below to verify properties of the CDF

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, continuity

Prove the following two results and use them to show that the CDF $F$ of a random variable is right-continuous and has limit from the left.

1. Let $X_1, X_2,....$ be a sequence of sets such that $X_n \subset X_{n+1} $ and let $X = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n = \cup_i X_i  $. Prove continuity from below: $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n) = P(X) $
2. Let $X_1, X_2,....$ be a sequence of sets such that $X_{n+1} \subset X_n$ and let $X = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n = \cap_i X_i$. Prove continuity from above: $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n) = P(X) $

Here is my attempt at the proof:

1. define $Y_1 = X_1$, $Y_n = X_n - X_{n-1} = X_n \cap X_{n-1}^C $

From the above definition, we have $X_n = \cup_{i=1}^n Y_i$ and therefore $ X = \cup_{i=1}^\infty Y_i $ since $ X = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n $

$\Rightarrow$ $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cup_{i=1}^{k} P(Y_i) = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} P(Y_i) = P(X) $

2. Since $X_{n+1} \subset X_n$, we have $X_1^C, X_2^C,...$ such that $X_n^C \subset X_{n+1}^C $.

Apply the result from part 1, $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n^C) = P(X^C) = P(\cup_i X_i^C) = P((\cap_i X_i)^C) $

Taking complements again, $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n) = P(X) = P(\cap_i X_i)$

3. Now to prove that a CDF $F$ is right continuous, I need to prove for any sequence ${x_n}$ such that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x_0  $ and $x_n > x_{n+1}$, we have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(x_n) = F(x_0)$

define $ A_n = \{ x \leq x_n \} $, which means that $ A_{n+1} \subset A_n $. Therefore, $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \{ x \leq x_0 \}$ (Is this true? How do I prove this?)

By result 2, $F(x_n) = P(X \leq x_n) = P(A_n) \rightarrow P(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = P(X \leq x_0) = F(x_0)$

4. To prove that $F$ has a limit to the left, I need to prove that for any sequence ${x_n}$ such that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x_0  $ and $x_n < x_{n+1}$, we have that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(x_n) = Pr(-\infty < X < x_0)$

define $ A_n = \{ x \leq x_n \} $, which means that $ A_{n} \subset A_{n+1} $. Therefore, $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \{ x < x_0 \}$ since $x  \leq x_n, x_n < x_{n+1}$, and $x_n \rightarrow x_0$

By result 1, $F(x_n) = P(X \leq x_n) = P(A_n) \rightarrow P(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = Pr(-\infty < X < x_0)$

I am not confident at every step of my attempt. Could someone quickly look over this and verify where I get it right/wrong and how I should correct my mistakes?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For right continuity, let $x_n\downarrow x$ and let $A_n = \{X\le x_n\},$ so that $F(x_n) = P(A_n).$ Then, $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_{n}$ (i.e. if $X\le x_{n+1}$ then $X\le x_n$), so we have a decreasing sequence and continuity from above applies and we have $$\lim_n F(x_n) = \lim_n P(A_n) = P(\bigcap_n A_n) = P(X\le x) = F(x).$$

You have all of that, except you want to know how to prove $\bigcap_n A_n = \{X\le x\}.$ It's just a matter of showing they're the same set of outcomes, and the way to do that carefully is to break it down into showing $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq,$ like this:

> If $X\in \bigcap_n A_n,$ then $X\le x_n$ for all $n,$ so $X\le x,$
> since $x$ is the greatest lower bound of the $x_n.$ Thus $\bigcap_n A_n \subseteq \{X\le x\}.$ Conversely, if
> $X\le x$ then since $x\le x_n$ for all $n,$ $X\le x_n$ for all $n,$ so $X\in \bigcap_n A_n.$ Thus $\{X\le x\}\subseteq \bigcap_n A_n.$

For left limits, similarly let $x_n\uparrow x$ and $A_n = \{X\le x_n\}.$ Now the sets are increasing and continuity from below gives $\lim_n F(x_n) = \lim_n P(A_n) =  P(\bigcup_n A_n).$ And that's it... this shows the left limit exists. (Also, we could just use the fact that $F$ is bounded and increasing and avoid needing to use continuity from below.)

As you indicate, you can go further and, similarly to the previous argument, show that $\lim_n F(x_n) = P(X < x),$ but that's not essential to showing the left limit exists. Note that the reason that we might not have left continuity is that it's possible that $P(X<x)<P(X\le x)$ (which holds iff $P(X=x) > 0$).